# Contextual menu shortcut in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans

Is there any way in Netbeans of displaying the contextual menu with the keyboard? I've tried Shift+F10 and the key next to the right Ctrl key with no success, but I can open it clicking with the right button.

Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shift+F10 is the official way in Netbeans 6.9. If this is not working for you, go to "Tools" - "Options" - "Keymap" and check which shortcut is assigned to "Popup"

Comment: You're right. But it didn't work for me with previous versions. Thank you.